# How come I can't use environment variables like this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mongoose, next.js

I have set up a monorepo for my project using lerna, and the `website` package is written using Next.

I have another package called `omega=lib` which acts as a library, and contains models/schemas for my mongo database. It also has a function that connects to it.

In my `website`, I am trying to fetch some data from the `Channel` schema (which exists in `omega-lib`), and the code for that looks like this:

**Channel.ts**

```
import { Schema, model, Document } from "mongoose";
import dbConnect from "../utils/dbConnect";

export interface IChannel extends Document {
    name: string
    logging_enabled: boolean
}

const ChannelSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, index: { unique: true } },
    logging_enabled: Boolean
});

const Channel = model<IChannel>('Channel', ChannelSchema);

export const getChannel = async (username: string) => {
    await dbConnect();
    return Channel.findOne({ name: username });
}

export default Channel;
```

I am trying to use this code in one of my pages, using `getServerSideProps`:

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (context: GetServerSidePropsContext<ParsedUrlQuery>) => {
  console.log("DB", process.env.MONGO_DB_URI);
  const userInfo: User = await getUser(context);
  const moderators: User[] = await getModerators(context);
  const channelInfo = await getChannel(userInfo.login);
  console.log("CHANNEL INFO", channelInfo);
  return {
    props: {
      userInfo,
      moderators,
      channelInfo
    }
  }
}
```

**IT IS WORTH NOTING, THAT ON LINE 2, THIS VALUE GETS LOGGED TO THE CONSOLE CORRECTLY!**

Here's where the problem starts, when this code rus, I get this error:

> MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.

This is coming from when the `dbConnect()` function is called. Here is the code for that:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const dbConnect = (uri?: string) => {
    if (mongoose.connection.readyState >= 1) {
        return;
    }

    return mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_DB_URI ?? uri, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
    })
}

export default dbConnect;
```

I do not see how `MONGO_DB_URI` can be null, it is defined in my `next.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    PRIVATE_KEY: "xxx",
    CLIENT_ID: "xxx",
    MONGO_DB_URI: "mongodb://localhost:27017/omegalogs",
    REDIRECT_URI: "http://localhost:3000/login",
    SCOPES: "user:read:email,moderation:read",
    WEBSOCKET_PORT: 9393
  },
};
```

And it is worth noting, that the correct value gets printed in the example code above, however it is `undefined` when being used in `dbConnect()`.

This `dbConnect()` function is defined in a the `omega-lib` package, but is used as a dependency. I don't think this is the problem, because it works fine in another project that has the same `MONGO_DB_URI` defined in the environment file.

This only works if I actually pass the `MONGO_DB_URI` environment variable through as a parameter to `dbConnect()`, which is why it is an optional string.

Can anyone tell me why the `dbConnect()` function is not picking up the environment variable? It should be doing this server side, so I don't see why it wouldn't.

Comment: Did you already try adding `console.log("DB", process.env.MONGO_DB_URI);` to both `Channel.ts` and `dbConnect.ts` just to confirm with 100% certainty that the process data is available?

Comment: @Forrest Yes, it is only ever undefined within `Channel.ts`

Comment: That seems odd though, why can you not `console.log()` the `MONGO_DB_URI` env variable in `Channel.ts`? If it's available via a modification to `dbConnect.ts` that seems even more odd.

Answer (score -1):

you already try to create a .env file and store the variables there for the process can see? you can install dotenv with:

```
npm i dotenv


//add dotenv to your index file
require('dotenv').config()

//this will in you .env file in the root of the project
PRIVATE_KEY: "xxx",
CLIENT_ID: "xxx",
MONGO_DB_URI: "mongodb://localhost:27017/omegalogs",
REDIRECT_URI: "http://localhost:3000/login",
SCOPES: "user:read:email,moderation:read",
WEBSOCKET_PORT: 9393

//now you can use in the same way
process.env.MONGO_DB_URI
```

is a easy way to do in my opinion

Comment: Next doesn't use a .env file